# top align text to image

Tags: html, css

I try to have a title and an author name on the right side of an image. The title has to be aligned with the top of the image as visible on the picture below.

[image: align title to top image]

I tried to play with paddings and margins but right now, here is what I get:

([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8xd9x4qh/))

```css
.post-head{
display: block;
position:relative;


}

.post-head-info {

  overflow:hidden;
  padding-top:0px;
  margin-top:0px;

}

.picture{
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

span{
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-head" >

  <div class="picture">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Japan-bio-stub.png" />
  </div> 

  <div class="post-head-info" >

    <h1>Title</h1>
    <span>Posted on by author</span> 

  </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing is caused by the `line-height` of your `h1`. If you reduce it to about 20px, it should mean your text starts at the top of the div.  Beware though that if your text wraps, it may cause your text to overlap or be close together as your font-size is 24px.

Another way would just be to add some minus margin to the h1.  Both examples are below:

```css
.post-head {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.post-head-info {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.picture {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

span {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.line-height {
    line-height:20px;
}

.minus-margin {
   margin-top:-4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-head">
  <div class="picture">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Japan-bio-stub.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-head-info">
    <h1 class="line-height">Title that might wrap Title that might wrap Title that might wrapTitle that might wrap</h1>
    <span>Posted on by author</span>
  </div>
</div><br>

<div class="post-head">
  <div class="picture">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Japan-bio-stub.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-head-info">
    <h1 class="minus-margin">Title</h1>
    <span>Posted on by author</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more of a hack than a solution but if you're looking for a quick fix:

```
h1 {
  margin-top:-5px;
}
```

Basically just use negative margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/8xd9x4qh/4/

Comment: I was just about to add the same answer. It *feels* hacky, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
.post-head-info {
   overflow:hidden;
   padding-top:0px;
   margin-top:0px;
   line-height: .8; /* Add that */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this that you are after? Play around with margins and sizes as you want.

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
div {
  margin-left: 6px;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Japan-bio-stub.png" />
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <span>Posted on by author</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
line-height: 1;
```

Negative margins are never usefull to use. Only for real must haves.
Or give the Picture a small margin-top

Answer (score 0):

I lowered the picture using percentages on margin-top. It seems like adjusting the image top positioning would be the way to fix this issue. After you may wanna lower picture and the title margin-top to be closer to the span.

```css
.post-head{
display: block;
position:relative;


}

.post-head-info {

  overflow:hidden;
  padding-top:-3px;
  margin-top:0px;

}

.picture{
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0.6%;
}

h1 {
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

span{
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-head" >

  <div class="picture">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Japan-bio-stub.png" />
  </div> 

<div class="post-head-info" >

  <h1>Title</h1>


  <span>Posted on by author</span> 



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the **line-height** of the **h1**.

```css
.picture img{
 float:left;
}

.post-head-info{
 line-height: 1.3em;
}

.post-head-info h1{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-head">
 <div class="picture">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Japan-bio-stub.png" />
 </div>
 <div class="post-head-info" >
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <span>Posted on by author</span> 
   </div>
</div>
```